# How do I access my environment variables for Eclipse in Yosemite?

Tags: environment-variables, osx-yosemite

I have a `local.catalina.properties` that accesses my environment variables to connect to my test db.  Here is the code:

```
ds.username=${env.ACCOUNT}
ds.password=${env.PW}
```

When I was running `Mavericks`, I had these variables defined in my `launchd.conf`, which has been deprecated in `Yosemite`.

I know that `GUI` apps don't read the `.bash_profile`, but I read that you could set the variables in the `.bash_profile` like this:

```
export ACCOUNT=username
export PW=password

launchctl setenv ACCOUNT $ACCOUNT
launchctl setenv PW $PW
```

This did not work.  I know that this has been discussed a lot in different forums, but I cannot find an answer that will work for me.  Can someone please tell me the right way to set these environment variables?

Comment: This actually does work, you need to restart the JVM for it to take affect.

Comment: I had another error.  You are right, it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set variables in your `.bash_profile` like this:

```
export ACCOUNT=username
export PW=password
```

and if you want it to be available to your GUI programs, then you can do this in the same file, under the variable declarations:

```
launchctl setenv ACCOUNT $ACCOUNT
launchctl setenv PW $PW
```

It was not working for me earlier, but I had another error.